# triggering different app environments with pyenv-virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, pyenv

with virtualenvwrapper, I could setup separate virtualenvs and calling workon *venv* have them link to specific settings files (ex. test_settings.py or dev_settings.py) I preset using hooks in the virtualenv's bin - preactivate, postactivate, predeactivate and postdeactivate.

Is there something equivalent for pyenv? pyenv-virtualenv automatically switches virtualenvs based on .python-version set in the current directory, so there's no need to activate and the .pyenv/versions/venv/bin/ dir doesn't have the compliment of hooks that virtualwrapper has anyway.

I can easily create different virtualenvs for my various app environments but how can I link them to different environment-specific app settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding environment variable `export something='something-else'` commands to the activate file `~/.pyenv/versions/my_venv/bin/activate` in the spirit of [autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv) after reading this [forum reply](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/how-to-manage-production-staging-dev-django-settings/21/3) elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

- The obvious one:  Try the `pyenv-virtualenvwrapper` plugin to pyenv?
- You can add hooks for a specific pyenv command in `$PYENV_ROOT/pyenv.d/<command>`. You can do this even for for pyenv’s “porcelain” commands which aren’t normally called directly by the user.  You could write a hook for `activate` that changes settings based on the name of the virtualenv you’re switching to.  (pyenv-virtualenv implicitly `pyenv activate` when switching to a virtualenv).  Note:  I’ve created pyenv hooks, but not for `activate`, so this is just an idea…